How do I delete a pivot table in an excel sheet using Robot Framework?
I have an excel sheet and few pivot tables in it. Now I would like to delete the pivot tables using Robot Framework.
I'm struck in the halfway through the code.
Clear Pivots
    [Arguments]    ${sheet_name}
    ${pivots}=    Get Pivot Tables
    FOR    ${tablename}    ${pivot}    IN    &{pivots}
        
    END 

